# Yii2: How not to have any date on edit in a datepicker field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker, yii2

As it is clear in the subject itself.

I have my datepicker fields blank at the time of creation and set to Null as default.

But I can't find a way to set a datepicker field to set it to blank again once a date is selected.

is there a way or I am missing something?

Comment: In my datepicker fields I just delete the date. Is there something else you wanted?